# DynamoDB Set of Objects Insert and Get

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I have the following DynamoDB Table

```
@Builder
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "rule_templates")
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DynamoRuleTemplate {
    private String id;
    private DataType dataType;
    private String displayName;
    private String helpText;
    private String expression;
    private Set<Param> params;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "data_type")
    public DataType getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "display_name")
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "help_text")
    public String getHelpText() {
        return helpText;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "expression")
    public String getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ParamSet.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "params")
    public Set<Param> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Here is the **Param** class:

```
@Data
public class Param {

    private DataType dataType;
    private String identifier;
    private String displayName;
    private String helpText;
}
```

I am pre-filling the table with some data in the form of json through AWS CLI like:

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "string-length-range"
  },
  "data_type": {
    "S": "STRING"
  },
  "display_name": {
    "S": "String length range"
  },
  "expression": {
    "S": "$val.length() <= $max && $val.length() >= $min"
  },
  "help_text": {
    "S": "String length range"
  },
  "params": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "dataType": {
            "S": "INTEGER"
          },
          "displayName": {
            "S": "max"
          },
          "identifier": {
            "S": "$max"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "dataType": {
            "S": "INTEGER"
          },
          "displayName": {
            "S": "min"
          },
          "identifier": {
            "S": "$min"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But while doing a GET from the table using JAVA application, I'm getting the following error for **params** field: *com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: expected S in value {L: [{M: {identifier={S: $max,}, displayName={S: max,}, dataType={S: INTEGER,}},}, {M: {identifier={S: $min,}, displayName={S: min,}, dataType={S: INTEGER,}, rule={M: {expression={S: $min >= 0,}},}},}],}*

Can someone help me with the correct json so that I don't get the above error?

Comment: In DynamoRuleTemplate class I can see a mismatch between types in your Class vs JSON which you gave. So attribute dataType is string ("S") in your DynamoDB JSON but the method getDataType() is returning DataType which do not have @DynamoDBTypeConverted to convert string to DataType

Comment: @AravindReddyP: My main question was regarding the json, the `params` field as that starts with L whereas I expect it to be a Set in the JAVA class `DynamoRuleTemplate`